# Create an Iframe from a Drupal Website

Tags: drupal, iframe

I have a drupal website. I want to generate an Iframe with content from my drupal site, that other sites can embed.

How I think this can be achieved:

**Method 1**: *Create a php script that is autonomous from the drupal engine.*

Import the configuration file and hence gain access to the database. Generate the content as a standalone webpage. Distribute the url of this script as the iframe's source url.
Problems: cannot provide drupal functionality within the iframe such as interaction with logged in user.

**Method 2**: *Create the iframe from within drupal.*

Create a new module that defines a menu entry using hoom_menu (the url for the iframe). Define the content of the iframe from the callback function of the menu entry. Then *Somehow* assign a custom page.tpl.php theme for the desired iframe url so that only the content of the iframe is rendered without all the other page elements (blocks, menus, footer, etc.).

Any comments especially for method 2 will be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have done exactly this, just this week!

I created a custom module that outputs only the content that I want (using `hook_menu()`). Then I created a page template (`page-mycustommodule.tpl.php`) that only has

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```

within the `<body>` tags.

That was basically all. To find out the name that your page template needs to have, use the `devel` and `theme_devel` modules, then just click on your page and it will tell you which templates it looked for.

One thing to look out for: any links in the iframe will only change the contents OF THAT FRAME, so when your module creates links, use the proper target to make the parent page jump to the new URL:

```
l('link text',
  'node/' . $mynode->nid,
   array('attributes' => array('target' => '_parent')));
```

Comment: Graham, what you describe works beautifully. Now that we have sorted the rendering of the iframe, any idea on how to make it more efficient - how to bypass preparing elements that are never rendered e.g. the blocks?

Comment: Not being a Drupal guru (yet), I'm not entirely sure how to prevent rendering of blocks. The Context module looks like it may do that (and much more), but I don't have any experience with it. The Block Page Visibility module also prevents unused blocks from being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by Graham very useful.  Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation on this site to add a comment so I will have to put my comment in an answer.

5 years on, the information has changed slightly:

- The module theme_devel now seems to be called devel_themer instead.
- In D7, the template naming pattern is slightly different with 2
  hyphens: page--[front|internal/path].tpl.php ([see docs](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656))
- D7 templates are slightly different based on render arrays, so the template will need to be something like `print render($page['content']);`

Answer (score 1):

#### method 3

you can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_iframe that allows you to create IFRAME READY webpages

install it and go to the display settings of you content type that you want to use as iframe content `admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENTTYPE/display`

choose the IFRAME view mode and choose the fields you would like to be shown

and then use url like this `domain.com/entity_iframe/node/NID` and you will have a display with no extra headers footers etc ...

By default a sample EMBED/IFRAME code is provided to the admin under each node the settings

```
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" src="domain.com/entity_iframe/node/96" frameborder="0" class="entity_iframe entity_iframe_node" id="entity_iframe_node_96" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

The settings in `admin/config/system/entity_iframe` control some of the details of the embed code

For complete control of the theme used you can use in combination with https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_iframe_theme

Comment: thanks GiorgosK it works fine between a Drupal Webform and a WordPress website!

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly need to iframe?
A node? A block? Should it be static or dynamic?
You can simply create a node with a php filter and generate the iframe output.
Then you can put this output between `<pre>` tags to display it as code that users can copy/paste in their site.