# How to use an iframe into Drupal?

Tags: drupal, iframe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an Iframe from a Drupal Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042366/create-an-iframe-from-a-drupal-website)

I'd like to use an iframe inside a "page" of drupal. It means that I want to load some pages of drupal inside an iframe. Actually, if I use an html code inside a page that describes an iframe, the drupal pages that'll be loaded inside, they'll show the full page of drupal : head,footer of drupal... Is it possible to only load the real content of a page?

Do you know an iframe adaptated for drupal?

Comment: why don't you use ajax instead?

Comment: Because I don't really know ajax. How can I use ajax to create a iframe?

Comment: I've seen a solution to create an iframe. The problem'll still the same. It'll display the full page of drupal (header, footer o drupal) and I only want to see the real content of a node.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The quick and dirty way:

In node content:

```
<div id="extraContent"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#extraContent").load("/path/to/node .content");
    });
</script>
```

**IMPORTANT**: The code above will obviously not work if user has JavaScript disabled AND will be laggy.

### The more reasonable way:

Add a "node reference" field through CCK to that node's content type and set "Full node" display to "Full node" ([here is a screenshot](http://i55.tinypic.com/j5v0wk.png))

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading this from the same Drupal install and you have permissions to use the php format you should be able to use the Drupal [node_load function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load).